# Jenkins: Get playload from gogs webhook

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, webhooks, gogs

I have a generic job that build docker image. And I want to call him with webhook with all my docker repositories.
I'm using Gogs plugin. But I can't figured out how to gather the playload send by gogs :/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's issues with using the Gitea plugin. Some are using the plugin for Gogs instead, or you could try the [Generic Webhook Trigger](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin) plugin.